# Download Zip file from Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a Spring Boot project with Java 11 which consists of an API to download the zip file which works fine. If I try to hit the API from the Swagger UI it show the option to download the file and when I click on it it downloads the file with a different name without any extension and does not consider the Content-Disposition header.

```
@GetMapping("/generate-report")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> generateReport(
      @RequestParam @Schema(example = "2023-01-01", description = "Format: yyyy-MM-dd")
          String startDate,
      @RequestParam @Schema(example = "2023-01-31", description = "Format: yyyy-MM-dd")
          String endDate,
      @RequestParam(required = false) @Schema(example = "99", description = "Project Id")
          List<Integer> projectIds)
      throws IOException {
    log.info("Request to generate report with start date: {}, end date: {}, project-id: {}",
        startDate, endDate, projectIds);

    List<String> filenames = reportService.generateReport(startDate, endDate, projectIds);
    String zipFilename = "Report_"
        +
        Instant.now().toString()
            .replace(":", "-")
            .replace("\\.", "-")
        +
        ".zip";

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + zipFilename);
    header.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    header.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    header.add("Expires", "0");

    try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFilename))) {
      for (String filePath : filenames) {
        File fileToZip = new File(filePath);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName()));
        Files.copy(fileToZip.toPath(), zipOut);
      }
    }

    File file = new File(zipFilename);
    long fileLength = file.length();

    Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

    filenames.add(zipFilename);
    deleteFiles(filenames);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(header)
        .contentLength(fileLength)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .body(resource);

  }
```

**openapi.yml**

```
openapi: 3.0.3
paths:
  /api/generate-report:
    get:
      tags:
        - report-controller
      description: Generate stats report for redmine and download it
      operationId: generateReport
      parameters:
        - name: startDate
          in: query
          description: "Format: yyyy-MM-dd"
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            description: "Format: yyyy-MM-dd"
            example: "2023-01-01"
          example: "2023-01-01"
        - name: endDate
          in: query
          description: "Format: yyyy-MM-dd"
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            description: "Format: yyyy-MM-dd"
            example: "2023-01-31"
          example: "2023-01-31"
        - name: projectIds
          in: query
          description: Project Id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            description: Project Ids
            example: "99"
          example: "99"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: On successful processing of request
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
          headers:
            Content-Disposition:
              schema:
                type: string
                description: header for file attachment
                example: attachment; filename="name.zip"
```